# Right clicking system tray icons causes both taskbar and application menus to appear

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, context-menu, notification-area

We recently got new company laptops for remote work so that we could stop having to remote into our old workstations on site. Aside from the always on VPN software, and offline sync being configured, they have been configured the same as the workstations. They are running Windows 10 20H2 with all security updates, with *lots* of group policy driven restrictions. And most importantly, they were set up from a clean base image for all company laptops rather than attempting to use images of our workstations.

I'm having a weird problem that nobody else seems to be having though... There are certain applications that have an icon in the system tray (I guess notification area is the term these days) that if I right click on them, both the menu for the application and the right click menu for the taskbar appear. The taskbar menu appears in front of the application one.

So far it has happened regularly with Microsoft Teams and Slack, with occasional instances with Logitech Setpoint. Here's every aspect of the behavior that I have observed:

- It is not every single right click, but somewhere in the 95-99% range.
- Holding right click and releasing without moving will make it happen.
- Holding right click and releasing after moving as little as one pixel will make it *not* happen.

  - The move can be over another tray icon, on the same tray icon, any taskbar application icon, or off the taskbar.
  - If the move stops over the empty space of the taskbar, or the date/time area, it will happen.
- The device used doesn't affect the behavior. I have confirmed this with the touchpad, my mouse, a backup mouse, and the PointStick.
- If the icons are in the "overflow" area it will not happen.

I guess ultimately it's a minor nuisance, but breaking the muscle memory of not moving during a right click has proven difficult. I've never experienced such behavior, and I haven't been able to figure out what's causing it.

I have tried:

- Reinstalling the affect programs.
- Doing a file system check.
- Changing taskbar settings.
- Exiting/disabling all possible applications that exist in the tray. (Some are forced by policy.)

Comment: Have you spoken with your IT staff? Frankly, if just get the computer reimaged at this point. This appears to be a software bug, and likely kinda deep in the OS given the symptoms.

Comment: @music2myear Re-imaging is the nuclear option and overkill for this minor bug. Our images are bare bones, and I'm a dev with a lot of software beyond the baseline.

Comment: I work with imaged systems too, and while the images are identical, there is still a small percentage of the systems that have errors that are fixed by reimaging. Also, our help section specifies that questions about corporate computers are usually off topic as the people responsible for resolving your computer problems will have information and may have applied settings (your comment about group policies) that you will not regarding the systems. If you ARE IT, that changes things some, but you must make this clear, and really, as IT, you should reimaged it.